# Trouble understanding the algebra in the graphic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I'm having trouble understanding the math below. I get Pythagoras' Theorem
but I don't understand the algebra.

We start with (R + $\Delta$)$^2$ = R$^2$ + X$^2$

Shouldn't one take: (R + $\Delta$)$^2$ and make it: R$^2$ + 2R$\Delta$ + $\Delta$$^2$?

Thus making it: R$^2$ + 2R$\Delta$ + $\Delta$$^2$ = R$^2$ + X$^2$

And then simplify?

Why does the answer just bring over the R? Where did the $\Delta$ go? After all the delta isn't infinitely small.

**EDIT:**

- Make R=10
- Make $\Delta$ = 1

Shouldn't that be

(10+1)$^2$ = 10$^2$ + x$^2$? =>

x$^2$ = (10+1)$^2$ - 10$^2$

Why does the $\Delta$ change the above process?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do things the way you suggest, it will be hard to solve for $\delta.$  From

$$(R+\delta)^2 = R^2 + x^2,$$

take the square root of both sides (both sides are positive):

$$ R+\delta = \sqrt{R^2+ x^2}$$

and subtract $R$" from both sides.  (This is why "just the $R$ is brought over.")

$$\delta = \sqrt{R^2+x^2} -R.$$

Where did the $\delta$ go?  It's still there, on the left side.  We solved for it.   Then they do this:

$$\delta = R\sqrt{1+(x/R)^2} - R$$

and then approximate the square root with the Taylor series:

$$\delta \approx R\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{R}\right)^2 \right)-R.$$

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Now I need to read up on the Taylor / Maclaurin but I get what was done.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta = \sqrt{R^2+x^2}-R$ comes from the original equation by taking square roots and simplifying.

Next, the Maclaurin series for $\sqrt{R^2+x^2}$ starts
$$R + \frac{x^2}{2R} + O(x^4),$$
so that
$$\sqrt{R^2+x^2}-R\approx R + \frac{x^2}{2R}-R\approx R\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2R^2}\right) - R = \frac{x^2}{2R}.$$

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand. :(  But I'll work on it and see if it makes more sense.